# separating relationships and model functions in Laravel

Tags: php, class, laravel

Everytime I'm writing a Laravel model it just gives me a feeling of messy code. I have relationships and other model functions specially when using domain driven design. So I though about separating relationships and functions.

Example I have a User class that extends Eloqeunt:

```
class User extends Eloquent{}
```

and inside this class I have register functions and password hashing functions etc. Also, we can declare the relationships so:

```
class User extends Eloquent{
    function post(){
        return $this->hasMany('POST');
    }
}
```

For some reason this smells funky to me. My solution was to create a Entities folder and inside create a User folder which will hold 2 files one would be UserRelationship which would hold of the the relationships for this class:

```
   class UserRelationship extends Eloquent{
        function post(){
            return $this->hasMany('POST');
        }
    }
```

and a second which would be the actual User class where I would write all of the functions and this class would extend the UserRelationship class instead of Eloquent:

```
class User extends UserRelationship{

    public static function register($email, $password, $activate_token)
    {
        $user = new static(compact('email', 'password', 'activate_token'));

        $user->raise(new UserWasRegistered($user));

        return $user;
    }
}
```

What do you guys think of this approach I am relatively new to all this so I don't know if this is bad practice or to much work for little reward. What do you guys recommend?

Comment: I don't like your solution at all.  The only time I would separate the relationship is if it could be shared by multiple models, in which case I would make it a trait.  Another better solution would be to create a UserRepository, feed it an instance of user, and then use the repository to do things like retrieve relations, insert new users, etc.

Comment: @Dave I do use repositories however with command driven design you end up having functions in your models and the repositories in the command handler class so the model has to much going on breaking the S SOLID

Answer (score 0):

For a user model, it is too much work. The easiest way and still a better approach is to define the relationship in the user model. If for example it is a post model where you have relationships for post to "user, comment, reply etc"  then you can attempt splitting your relationships